# Compare two DataFrames using PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working on a project where I need to compare two dataframes. I initially utilized the compare function offered by Pandas to accomplish this task. The output from the compare function provides the desired result. However, I need to accomplish the same task, but with big data. How can I use PySpark to compare two dataframes in the same way?

pandas.DataFrame.compare
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html

I reviewed the Apache Spark documentation, but wasn't able to find a Pandas API on Spark that's relevant to the above goal.

Pandas API on Spark
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/frame.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check this package datacompy

Initially it was built for pandas later it was extended for spark dataframes as well.

https://capitalone.github.io/datacompy/

```
pip install datacompy
```

> The main use case for datacompy is when you need to interpret the difference between two dataframes.

---

There is one more thing called spark-diff:

https://github.com/G-Research/spark-extension/blob/master/DIFF.md

You can check the code given in the example for refernce.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in Spark that does that out of the box. You can do a full join of two dataframes on a common key, then check all rows that contain mismatches.